# Login to a Spring-powered website using one's Facebook account

Tags: facebook, spring, authentication, spring-social

I would like for users of my website to be able to login to my website **using their Facebook account**. My website is going to be powered by **the Spring framework**.

Can Spring Social help me or do I need to create a Facebook app?

Any general guidance, advice or pointer welcome.

Comment: Spring Social can help you with this (that’s what it’s _for_, besides some other stuff) – but you will still need to create an app to get it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The accepted answer is technically correct in saying that Facebook is not an OpenID provider. However, OpenID is not the only way that this can be accomplished.

Spring Social's ProviderSignInController can be used to do a "sign-in-with-{provider}" authentication, where {provider} can be any OAuth-secured API, including Facebook. See the Spring Social Showcase for an example of how this is done.

Comment: You do still need to create a Facebook app, too, as you will need your Facebook app's token and secret to configure Spring Social.